# Can't retrieve list of documents from Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to retrieve list of document using admin SDK and firestore api on my firebase functions. 
I have tried to use the following:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const adminFirestore = admin.firestore();
    adminFirestore.collection('accounts');

        collection.get().then(snapshot => {

            snapshot.forEach(doc => {

                console.log( doc.data() );

            });

        });
```

However, this wont print the individual documents  in this collection. 
I have also tried the following:

```
const ref = adminDb.ref('accounts');

ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot);
    });

ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());

}).then(something => {

    console.log(something);

})
```

Nothing really does print the documents in the collectin. All I get is a reference to the collection, and it's not very clear how to receive the entries in this collection. 
Any suggeastions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not far! As shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) in the doc, you indeed have to use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=0#get) method, but your problem comes from the fact that you haven't declared the `collection` variable.

You should do as follows:

```
const adminFirestore = admin.firestore();
const collection = adminFirestore.collection('accounts');  

collection.get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
       console.log( doc.data() );
    });
});
```

or, other possibilities, as follows:

```
const adminFirestore = admin.firestore();
adminFirestore.collection('accounts').get().then(snapshot => {...});
```

or as follows:

```
admin.firestore().collection('accounts').get().then(snapshot => {...});
```

---

Note that with your second try, by doing `const ref = adminDb.ref('accounts');` you are actually targeting the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/?authuser=0), which is different from the [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/?authuser=0) database (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Database?authuser=0#ref). They are both products/services offered by Firebase, but are different.